# reading Persian string from .ini File

Tags: c#, string, character-encoding, ini, farsi

I save a parameter (a `Persian text`) manually to `.ini` File. Now I want to read it in `C# (WPF)` using this Code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(
    string Section, 
    string Key, 
    string Default, 
    StringBuilder RetVal, 
    int Size, 
    string FilePath);
```

When I want to show it using MessageBox, I get some `un-known characters`. Even I tried this code for encoding (with different type of encoding):

```
        var enc = Encoding.Default;
        var bytes = enc.GetBytes(_address);
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(
            _address);
```

but I still see, unknown character. `_address` is aforementioned Persian parameter, which as retrieved using `GetPrivateProfileString` method (as retVale). I note that I can see the string is saved normally (in NotePad with UTF-8). How can I fix this problem?

Comment: how are you setting _address?

Comment: Don't you know what encoding was used to store that string? Did you use `WritePrivateProfileStringW`? Have you tried `Encoding.Unicode` or `Encoding.UTF8`?

Comment: @Stefan. `_address` is aforementioned Persian parameter, which as retrieved using `GetPrivateProfileString` method (as retVale).

Comment: Btw, you can read the BOM of that file with a hex editor (or a StreamReader): Unicode (UTF16-LE) BOM is `FF FE`, UTF8, if present, is `EF BB BF`.

Comment: Also, you can read the chars instead of a string, changing `StringBuilder RetVal` in  `[In, Out] char[] RetVal`

Comment: Use a native C# solution such as https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser